# What is the best experience for long mobile questionnaires?

Tags: usability, mobile, questionnaire

I am designing an app where the user is allowed to select multiple services which lead to a questionnaire around each service. If the user selects all the services this potentially could be a very long multi-part questionnaire, however this based on research would be an edge case.

I am playing around with two options:

1. Using a stepper, which also acts as a navigation. i.e the user can tap on step 2 and be redirected to that page.

Pros - Provides insight into how many pages are left
     - Smaller chunks of information which makes filling out all these questions less daunting.

Cons - Not scalable, as we add more services or questions the stepper can only show so many steps on a mobile screen.

Technically can be quite large to implement for a small size of value.

2. Place all the questions on one page.

Pros - Users can scroll to the end to estimate how large it is
Cons - Users might drop off based on the amount of questions.

My question is, has anyone done this before and is willing to provide insight onto what worked for them, or if any of these options from a usability perspective trumps the other.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of taking offence at how your question title is worded. I don't think there is *a* best experience to be provided for all questionnaires (or any other kind of content) regardless of context and content :-)

Comment: How would you re-word it?

Comment: Maybe "How to help users manage effort expectations when having to fill long questionnaires on a mobile device?". I'm under the impression this is what you're asking about specifically since they *have* to fill the questionnaires. Though I'm also curious if, in your specific app context, your users need to fill all questionnaires right away or if some could be delayed to when they need to use the corresponding service? Or if some of the questionnaires could be factored?

Comment: All good points! The questionnaires produce a quote for a certain service so for example with a moving company the idea is to understand how much furniture there is and how large that furniture is. Unfortunately that means that the questionnaire needs to ask the user to go from one room to another documenting each piece of furniture they would like placed in a van. The questionnaire could be relatively small (studio apartment) or pretty long and tedious - and all needs to be asked upfront in order to get to the quote.

Comment: Right, so in that case there's the generic question about communicating the workload when it has to be split, and your specific options. Have you considered working on the questionnaires themselves to make them more compact or faster to process? e.g. using pre-selections of ranges of item numbers / volumes (if your userbase isn't likely to misestimate)? Or if the list of items moved is standard for your user base, showing visual representations of the typical items they need moved rather than make them type or click small buttons? If you can reduce the workload locally you're improving UX too.

Answer (score 1):

Try pagination (2/10) and navigation arrows.

Although your system should allow for huge number of questions, I feel the problem lies in the design of the surveys.

Are all those questions necessary? There are only so many questions the user will answer before frustration kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to one of my project I am working on. I m attaching img below, I ll suggest you can show the selected services on the top and questions will be loaded depending upon which tab is clicked. The questions will have next,prev actions and also it will show progressive bar to know the user how much % he is completed the questionairies. 
[image: sample question]